# JUnit 5, how to get parameterized test parameter from BeforeEach callback?

Tags: java, junit, junit5

I have the following set of methods in different classes:

```
@ParameterizedTest
@MethodSource("com.myapp.AppleProvider#getApplesDependingOnConditions")
public void testSomething(Apple apple) {
   SomeContainer.getInstance().setApple(apple)
   // ...
}
```

The problem is that I cannot avoid copy/pase of the following

- `name` argument for each test call
- The very first line of each test - `SomeContainer.getInstance().setApple(apple)`

I tried to use extension points - `BeforeTestExecutionCallback` and `BeforeEachCallback`, but they don't seem to have ability to get parameter with which they are being called.

According to https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/1139 and https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/944 it's not possible to access argument passed to test from extension points yet and parameterized tests don't work for `BeforeEach` callbacks.

So I'm basically looking for any workaround so that my test could look like:

```
@MyAwesomeTest
public void testSomething() {
   // ... 
}
```

Where `@MyAwesomeTest` encapsulates two annotations above.

What I've already found:

- In extension points the following data is available: `displayname`, `method` or `tags`. If I pass argument into the each test method (though it's very undesirable) looks like I can rely on `displayname` since it'll reflect argument passed to the method call for a particular parameter.
  I'm trying to find out whether there're any other ways without need to add argument into each method.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could cheat to get most of the way there:

```java
public static Stream<String> apples() {
  return com.myapp.AppleProvider
    .getApplesDependingOnConditions()
    .stream()
    .peek(apple -> SomeContainer.getInstance().setApple(apple))
    .map(apple -> { /* convert to name string */ })
}

@ParameterizedTest
@MethodSource("apples")
public void testSomething(String name) {
   // ...
}
```

Comment: Hi, my goal is to call `setApple` exactly before the test method with one parameter at time (current one), but here looks like each test execution apples() will be called and `setApple` will be called twice

Comment: Why do you believe `setApple` will be called twice? Streams are lazily evaluated, so each call to `setApple` in `peek` should occur just before the test method is executed, unless JUnit gathers the entire output of the stream into a collection before executiong the test methods.